# Realtime Database price vs Firebase CloudStore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First, I read the documents on the Firebase. And it is still not neatly organized. I'm going to publish kind of an app for the first time.
That's why I get a lot of confusion.
I think this is a place for beginners to ask questions also.

It has only one photo on profile in my app.
I mean my app is text-centric, not photos.

I think the Realtime-Database would be advantageous because it requires less storage space.

But bandwidth is a problem. I do not know exactly what the bandwidth is. Bandwidth is said to occur when downloading, but when reading text into my database is it called bandwidth?

I do not have much money and I want to try it in an optimized environment. What do you think would be better?

My app doesn`t need photos other than profile pictures that can identify each user.

I am a beginner, so the contents of the documents are difficult and I am asking questions. 
I don't want you to think it is a duplicate question.

Comment: did you check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#pricing)?

Comment: Why does it require less storage space?

Comment: @eckes because users need only one picture. is it incorrect?

Comment: Yes, If a user has only one picture then you need to store only one picture for each user, that’s correct for all types of database.

Comment: So I said I need less storage space. you know it`s not kind of Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

In firebase realtime database bandwidth is calculated for data transferred from the database (and it is given a quota for the month). If you go through their docs you can get a nice idea. Here's the [link](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)  to their pricing documentation.

To store your one image (as far as i know) you'll have to use "storage" in the firebase and save the reference in the firebase database.
Since your app is text based, you can most probably get away with their free tier, which is cool. Have fun, hope this helps you

here's the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) to their database documentation.

Comment: you mean, Is the text-based app almost free?

Comment: yes, database and storage services and many functionalities. There's a free tier. But that all depends on the user count of your application. If your user base grows larger, you would have to upgrade to a different plan they've providing that meet your requirements